# How to handle keyboard shortcuts using keyPressEvent()? And should it be used for it?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, shortcut

While defining the custom signal emission from within `QTableView`'s `keyPressEvent()` method:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, e):
    if e.text()=='w':
        self.emit(SIGNAL('writeRequested'))
    if e.text()=='o':
        self.emit(SIGNAL('openRequested'))
```

I am using incoming `e` argument to figure out what keyboard key was pressed. With this "technique" I am limited to only one character at the time. Secondly, I am not able to use a combination of `Ctrl+Key`, `Alt+Key` or `Shift+Key`. Third, I can't figure out what `Delete` and `Backspaces` keys are so I could compare them against `e.text()`.

So there are few questions really...

1. Where in Qt docs all the keyboardKeys are listed so they could be used to do a `e.text()=='keyboardKey'` comparison.
2. How to handle the double-keyboard keys combinations (such as `Ctrl+Key`) with the "technique" I am using (sending a custom signal from inside of view's `keyPressEvent()`?
3. Is there an alternative easier way to hook the keyboard keys to trigger a method or a function (so the user could use keyboard shortcuts while mouse positioned above `QTableView` to launch the "action")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the signature of [`keyPressEvent()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent) you will see that the `e` argument you describe in your question is of type [`QKeyEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeyevent.html).

`QKeyEvent` instances have a method [`key()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeyevent.html#key) which returns an integer that can be matched against constants in the enum [`Qt.Key`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#Key-enum).

For example:

```
if e.key() == Qt.Key_Backspace:
    print 'The backspace key was pressed'
```

Similarly, `QKeyEvent` has a method [`modifiers()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeyevent.html#modifiers). Because there can be multiple keyboard modifiers pressed at once, you need to use this a little differently. The result from `modifiers()` is the binary OR of one or more of the constants in the [`Qt.KeyboardModifier`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#KeyboardModifier-enum) enum. To test if a given modifier is pressed, you need to perform the binary AND. For example:

```
if e.modifiers() & Qt.ShiftModifier:
    print 'The Shift key is pressed'

if e.modifiers() & Qt.ControlModifier:
    print 'The control key is pressed'

if e.modifiers() & Qt.ShiftModifier and e.modifiers() & Qt.ControlModifier:
    print 'Ctrl+Shift was pressed'
```

Note: In the example above, if both ctrl+shift were pressed, then all three if statements execute, in sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness and if you want more difficult sequences (ctrl-c followed by ctrl-k for example) just use [QKeySequence](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html) as shortcut of a [QAction](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html) which can be added to any [QWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#addAction).